# Assembly - How to properly store user input and print it?

Tags: linux, assembly, scanf, nasm, x86-64

I just started learning asm and I am trying to make a program that asks the user for input(N) and prints the numbers from 1 to N.
The problem is that when i try to print the value i get from scanf if it doesn't work. And the loop just prints ";".

Here is what i have so far:

```
section .data
   msg db "Enter a number: "
   fmt db "%d", 0

section .bss
   N resb 1

section .text
extern scanf

global main

main:

   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, msg
   mov rdx, 15
   syscall

   mov rax, 0
   mov rdi, fmt
   mov rsi, N
   call scanf
```

Here is where I try to print number N i got from scanf

```
   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, N
   mov rdx, 1
   syscall
```

And the loop

```
   mov rcx, 0
loop:
   inc rcx

   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, rcx
   mov rdx, 1
   syscall

   cmp rcx,[N]
jne loop
```

Close the program

```
   mov rax,60
   mov rdi,0
   syscall
```

This is how i compile:

```
 nasm -f elf64 -o program.o program.asm
 gcc -o program program.o
```

Comment: Your `scanf` resulted in an integer in binary format (by the way, that's 4 bytes, so you should use `resd`). You can't just print it like that, you need to convert it back to text, e.g. by using `printf`. PS: if you are using C library you should not use `exit` system call, rather, return from `main` or `call exit`. Mixing C stdio with syscalls is a bad idea too. Stick to one or the other.

Comment: @Jester Why is "Mixing C stdio with syscalls is a bad idea too." true? Are you primarily referring to coding standards or possible memory, register corruption due to poor clean up program exit?

Comment: Yes, the `exit` syscall terminates the process immediately, no chance for libc to clean stuff up (e.g. flush file buffers). Mixing abstraction levels is a bad idea in general.